# Get list of files changed by GitHub Pull Request using git

Tags: git, github, github-actions, pull-request, git-workflow

As a part of PR validation, I need to detect what files have changed in PRs created from forked repositories to my main repository.

Currently, I am using this code:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
- name: Get changed files
  id: changed-files
  uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v34
```

But the problem is that it also returns all files modified inside my main repository that were done after PR was opened on top of just Pull Request changes as `checkout` is doing a merge there. More detailed description of this problem [here](https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files/issues/714)

I am looking for the best option to get ONLY the files listed in PR "Files changes" tab.
I cannot work with GitHub CLI (which will be the easiest) as I don't want to share secrets with forked repositories for that, so I have to rely only on git commands.

Comment: Can you run a git command? That is done with a diff with `...` (3 dots). So, `git diff --name-only target-branch...feature-branch`

Comment: @eftshift0 it's not between branches - both branches are "main" but those are separate repository - main one and forked one

Comment: That doesn't matter. As long as you have visibility of both branches on a repo (as remote branches, or one local and the other remote), it can be done: `git diff --name-only main-remote/main...forked-remote/main` or `git diff --name-only main-remote/main...main`

Comment: @eftshift0 I will give it a try - does it make sense then to checkout PR head and add main repository as remote? 
By default `actions/checkout` is doing merge which I think will mess up everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using just this for PRs:

```
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
     fetch-depth: 2
- name: Get changes
  run: git diff --name-only -r HEAD^1 HEAD | xargs
```

Seems like it's enough, as checkout is doing a merge commit when checking out pull requests.

Comment: What about using `${{ github.base_ref }}` instead of `HEAD^1` ?
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context